# Sortable messes up my database ordering

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using Jquery UI as a frontend and PHP with MYSQL as a backend. My problem arises when I open the sort page for the first time, it messes up my entire order. For example:

```
id|text|orderid|
----------------  
1 |abc |2      |  
2 |bca |4      |  
3 |zxc |6      |  
4 |qwe |3      |  
5 |ads |1      |  
6 |iul |5      |
```

becomes:

```
id|text|orderid|
----------------
1 |abc |5      |  
2 |bca |1      |  
3 |zxc |3      |  
4 |qwe |6      |  
5 |ads |4      |  
6 |iul |2      |
```

my index.php(HTML+JS): http://pastebin.com/5F66ncVF
my updatedb.php(PHP&mysql queries): http://pastebin.com/3zhRvgvB

Please Help?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't had time to really go through your data but this is what I use to get my data on my ajax call:

```
var data = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('toHierarchy', {startDepthCount: 1});
```

I explicitly set the handle and items so sortable knows where to get the data from:

```
$('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
    handle: 'div',
    items: 'li',
    ...
```

For debugging, I send data to this using `console.log(data);`

```
//for nested sortable
function dump(arr,level) {
    var dumped_text = "";
    if(!level) level = 0;

    //The padding given at the beginning of the line.
    var level_padding = "";
    for(var j=0;j<level+1;j++) level_padding += "    ";

    if(typeof(arr) == 'object') { //Array/Hashes/Objects
        for(var item in arr) {
            var value = arr[item];

            if(typeof(value) == 'object') { //If it is an array,
                dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' ...\n";
                dumped_text += dump(value,level+1);
            } else {
                dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' => \"" + value + "\"\n";
            }
        }
    } else { //Strings/Chars/Numbers etc.
        dumped_text = "===>"+arr+"<===("+typeof(arr)+")";
    }
    return dumped_text;
}
```

Maybe give that a try first and if not I can look into your code a bit further...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however nestedSortable is not a function of the main JQuery UI, and searching for it netted me multiple results of which all failed me. My code works perfectly for ASC ordering, however when ordering by DESC it messes itself up.

Comment: try setting the items and handle as in my example just usiing jquery sortable: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items and http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle for the examples of how. Also, try doing this after you load all the contents of the sortable (so within $(document).ready(function(){ $( ".selector" ).sortable( "refreshPositions" ); });

Comment: Thank you scott, however this is still not fixing my problem, I don't think that this is an Javascript problem, as the script works perfectly when I set the MYSQL query to ASC, only in the cases when I try to use DESC does the above mentioned problem rear its ugly head.